# Is there a way to (auto) fetch composer's environment information internally?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I have a composer environment that is deployed on a GKE cluster, my wish is to be able to retrieve the info on this cluster via `operators` for example, without hard coding it, or manually putting it in environment variables.

Relevant info I wish to get for now :

```
COMPOSER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT = "<acc_name>@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
COMPOSER_BUCKET = "<bucket_name>"
COMPOSER_PROJECT = "<project_id_where_composer_is_deployed>"
COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION = "3.8.12"
COMPOSER_VERSION = "<relevant_v>"
COMPOSER_UI_URL = "<...>"
AIRFLOW_VERSION = "2.3.4"
...
```

My intuition is to use `gcloud` via a `BashOperator`, but I was hoping there was a library capable of performing this task better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [CloudComposerGetEnvironmentOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/cloud_composer.html) operator :

```py
get_env = CloudComposerGetEnvironmentOperator(
        task_id="get_env",
        project_id='project',
        region='europe-west1',
        environment_id='composer-env-name',
)
```

This operator displays all the environment information, it's equivalent to :

```bash
gcloud composer environments describe composer-env-name \
  --location europe-west1
```

You can access to the result `Dict` with [xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) if needed.

If you want to no hard coding the arguments like `project id` and `Composer` `environment name`, you can retrieve them with [predefined Composer env vars](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables), example :

```py
PROJECT_ID = os.getenv("GCP_PROJECT")
COMPOSER_ENV_NAME = os.getenv("COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT")

get_env = CloudComposerGetEnvironmentOperator(
        task_id="get_env",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        region='europe-west1',
        environment_id=COMPOSER_ENV_NAME,
)
```

Comment: I'd still have to specify `composer-env-name` and `project_id`.. something the environment should know about itself. In the console for example when you display the env info, these things are available.

Comment: The idea is that those values are automatically deduced without hard coding or explicitely specifying them, in case I want to switch between environments. `dev` would have a composer env, `prod` would aswell, but the dags running within them should remain the same.

Comment: You can use `Composer` predefined env vars, I edited my answer to show you an example in this direction.

Comment: @Imad have you solved your issue ?

Comment: thank you veyr much ! I will test it today and validate your answer!